# How to enable bundling in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bundle

I was playing a little bit to prevent bundling files and now I am stuck at how to return them to be a bundled.

I tried to set `debug=false`, also I entered BundleOptimization to true and I have files separated.

My `BundleCOnfig.cs` looks like:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        #region Styles bundles

        var bundlesCSS = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.css")
            //.Include("~/Content/css/libs/fontawesome/font-awesome.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/camera/camera.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/fontawesome/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper());

        var bundlesCustom = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/custom")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/general.css")

        bundlesCSS.Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer();
        bundlesCustom.Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer();
        bundles.Add(bundlesCSS);
        bundles.Add(bundlesCustom);

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/hotel-datepicker-css").Include(
            "~/Content/css/libs/baguetteBox.min.css",
            "~/Content/css/hotel-datepicker/hotel-datepicker.css"
            ));

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and my `web.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" 
             type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below line of code in `Application_Start()` of  Global.asax.cs file?

```
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

if yes, then `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` enables bundling and minification in debug mode. If you set it to `false` then it will not do bundling and minification.